# Proof that $A_5$ is simple

Tags: group-theory

The thing I don't understand about the proof is that we are using the fact that $A_5$ contains all its three cycles. I can't see why this doesn't prove $A_4$ is simple. How can we use this argument when it should also work for $A_4$?

Also, why can we just break down $A_5$ into three types?

1. $2^2$
2. $1^2 3^1$
3. $5^1$

Surely you have to include $4^1 1^1$ and $3^1 2^1$ too. However, in written notes it doesn't do this.

Also, does $A_4$ contain all three cycles? Maybe I'm incorrectly assuming this.

[image]

I'm trying to understand this proof. It's written notes that I have scanned.

Comment: Can you post the proof to which you are referring?

Comment: The product of a 3-cycle 2-cycle is an odd permutation, so is not in $A_5.$ The first part of your question makes it unclear what is being asked. The usual proof is that $A_n$ is generated by its $3$-cycles for $n >2,$ and hence once a normal subgroup contains a $3$-cycle, it is all of $A_n.$ For $n >4,$ it is possible to prove that any non-trivial normal subgroup of $A_n$ contais a $3$-cycle, but this does not work for $n = 4.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Okay that cleared it up. Hmm. Yes I sort of understand your comment. I suppose it makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every three-cycle is a product of two transpositions.  So yes, $A_4$ also contains all three-cycles.
But the crucial point is that every normal subgroup of $A_5$ that has more than one element also contains all three-cycles.
Since the three-cycles generate $A_5$, every normal subgroup of $A_5$ with more than one element is all of $A_5$.

To show that every subgroup of $A_5$ with more than one element contains all three cycles, you go by cases:  every non-identity element of $A_5$ is a 3-cycle, or a 5-cycle, or a product of two disjoint transpositions.
By conjugation and multiplication you can cook up every three-cycle from such an element.  But this needs space, i.e., if the set that your permutations act on has only 4 elements, you don't have the permutations that you want to conjugate 
with.

My answer is assuming you have a full proof of the simplicity of $A_5$ in front of you.  If not, you will find one searching the internet.

Comment: So to prove that $A_5$ has a 3-cycle you are suggesting I look at all conjugates in $A_5$ of the form $g(abcde)g^{-1}$ and $g(ab)(cd)g^{-1}$ where $g\in A_5$? No matter what I must always be able to obtain a 3-cycle from this?

Comment: I will write more soon, but for now a short answer:  No, conjugates of 5-cycles are 5-cycles and conjugate of products of disjoint transpositions are products of disjoint transpositions.  So it is more complicated than you suggest.

Comment: Ok, look at the handwritten notes.  What happens is that you get the required 3-cycles as $g^{-1}(edcba)g(abcde)$ and $g^{-1}(dc)(ba)g(ab)(cd)$.  If $(abcde)$ is in the normal subgroup, then so is $g^{-1}(edcba)g(abcde)$ and similarly for $(ab)(cd)$.